# How can I ship luggage from Chennai to Madurai in India?

Tags: luggage, shipping, chennai

I'll be arriving in Chennai from Chicago on September 11th at around 3 am and same day at 6 am I'll be flying to Madurai with Jet Airways. I'm carrying two pieces of luggage weighing approximately 20 kg each. Jet Airways baggage policy allows only one item of baggage weighing 15 kg for domestic travel and their excess baggage charges are way too expensive (Rs. 300 per kg).

What are the options available in Chennai airport for safely shipping my luggage to Madurai?

Is there any 24 hrs domestic cargo handling service within Chennai airport that I can use for shipping my luggage?

Comment: At 300 Rs per kg, I think you will find taking it on the plane with you to be less expensive than shipping it by air cargo, DHL, FedEx, etc.  A quick quote from FedEx is 13958 Rs vs 6000 Rs on Jet Airways.

Comment: Are these separate bookings or the same booking?